# Finding thermal resistance and capacitance from thermal impedance curve

Tags: impedance, matlab, thermal

I'm trying to calculate thermal resistance and capacitance from the thermal impedance curve with data taken from the thermal impedance graph using non-linear curve fitting method on MATLAB.

The thermal impedance time constant formula is attached. I'm new to the curve fitting methods so it is difficult for me to follow. Any help on how to go about this would be appreciated.

[image: Thermal impedance vs time]

[image: Thermal impedance- time constant formula]

Comment: Are you trying to find these as an exercise?  The device's datasheet should have the thermal resistance at least.

Comment: Why did you add the [tag:ltspice] tag?

Comment: Because I'm doing the final modelling in LTspice

Comment: @wheats Well, that's nice but, it has nothing to do with the question. That will be just what you'll be doing *after* you find out the answer to your problem, not part of the problem, itself.